# Large size or greater creatures on the battlefield

Tags: pathfinder-1e

So as small and medium sized creatures take up 1 square, does anyone know how many squares Large/Huge/Gargantuan creatures take up in Pathfinder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Creature sizes are detailed in [this table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates/#TOC-Creature-Sizes)

```
Size        Space
----------  ---------
Large       10' (2x2)
Huge        15' (3x3)
Gargantuan  20' (4x4)
Colossal    30' (6x6) (or larger)
```

(Also included at that link are diagrams showing size and reach)